# Get week numbers with start and end dates between two dates in php

Tags: php, date, date-difference

I would like to get week numbers with start and end dates between two dates in php. Weekdays are from Monday to Saturday.

For Example:

```
$date1='2018-03-21';
$date2='2018-05-14';
```

I want the output to be something like

```
Week no    Start Date    End Date
Week1      2018-03-21    2018-03-24
Week2      2018-03-26    2018-03-31
```

And so on.

How should I manage things to get this?

I am trying to use strtotime() function but no idea how will I get the desired output.

Comment: have you tried the date function date('W');

Comment: @NirojMaharjan can you elaborate the  code please?

Comment: When you use that date function with the W parameter it returns the week number for you
PS it will return the week number of the year not the month

Comment: What's the output for `$date2='2018-05-14';`? Also, till when we have to keep printing these weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative if to use `DateTime` class with the `->modify` method. It helps to you adjusts the date via relative dates.

Here's the idea: (the markup is up to you, or put it inside an array, whichever you prefer)

```
$i = 1; // week number starts at 1
$date1 = new DateTime('2018-03-21');
$date2 = new DateTime('2018-05-14');
while (true) {
    echo "Week {$i}\n";
    echo $date1->format('Y-m-d'), ' - ';
    $date1->modify('next saturday');
    if ($date1 >= $date2) {
        echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');
        break; // stop the loop, reached the end date, echo the last date, or whatever you want
    }
    echo $date1->format('Y-m-d') , "\n";    
    $date1->modify('next monday'); // start again on monday
    $i++; // increment for next week
}
```

[Here's a sample fiddle](https://3v4l.org/A31PJ)

Sidenote: If you want to know more or for in-depth info about what you can use on relative dates, here's the documentation entry:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: new Datetime is not working and gives blank page no error. My code is echo $date1=new DateTime($_POST["curriculum_start_date"]);
echo $date2=new DateTime($_POST["curriculum_end_date"]);

Answer (score 0):

Use the date() function with "W".  It will return the week number starting on a Monday.

```
$array = array(

  '2018-03-21',
  '2018-05-14',
  '2018-01-20',
  '2018-06-05',
  '2017-11-15'

);

echo
'<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Week #</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
  </tr>';

  foreach($array as $date){

    echo
    '<tr>' .
      '<td>' . date('W', strtotime($date)) . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . '' . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . '' . '</td>' .
    '</tr>';

  }

echo
'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that loops Unix times.

```
$date=strtotime('2018-03-21');
$date2=strtotime('2018-05-14' . '23:39');

While($date <= $date2){
    $new[date("W", $date)]['start'] = date("Y-m-d", $date);
    $new[date("W", $date)]['end'] = date("Y-m-d", $date + (6-date("N", $date))*86400); // next saturday
    $date = $date + (8-date("N", $date))*86400; // set date to next Monday.
}
$w =array_keys($new);

$new[end($w)]["end"] = date("Y-m-d", $date2); // edit last item to end date
Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/nMk0X